# Simple spring-boot using gateway configured to a UI based route throws 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I created a simple spring-boot app using gateway framework.

The configuration is shown below for the routes:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: rewritepath_route
        uri: http://example.org
        predicates:
        - Path=/foo/**
        filters:
        - RewritePath=/foo(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}

      - id: gateway_test_route
        uri: http://example.org
        predicates:
        - Path=/test
```

However going to any of the following routes only shows a 404:

- http://localhost:8280/test
- http://localhost:8280/foo/
- http://localhost:8280/actuator/gateway

Going to this endpoint

- http://localhost:8280/foo

shows HTTP Error code 500 Internal Server Error

Going to the actuator point:

- http://localhost:8280/actuator/

this works fine

Not sure if this is an issue or not but the routes were obtained from the gateway docs.

I have uploaded the code on [github.](https://github.com/drgeb/api-gateway-404-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with S-C-G, but when you call your application via localhost, the 'uri' will be 'localhost' and not 'example.org'.

When testing this route locally, you need to pass a suitable HTTP 'Host' header with a tool like Postman or curl. Perhaps there are browser plugins as well.

So try passing 'Host: example.org' when doing the request to your locally running application.